# How to read file content line per line

Tags: batch-file

How I can read line per line the content of a text file?

I've tried

```
Type "Text.txt"
```

I will read the complete output

Comment: Just a suggestion please use Google before asking easy things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%a IN (
    "File.txt"
) DO (
    Echo %%a
)

Pause&Exit
```

Comment: Your code doesn't read empty lines. `Tokens=*` is not necessary here. Do not use `%%#`, if you have more than one token, you need an ASCII table. Moreover, this is not the best programming style.

Comment: @endoro has a good point - alpha loop variables are documented and are more appropriate for newbies to use.  I made some edits to clarify the code.