# Delete files from folder [Windows]

Tags: windows, batch-file

The problem is as follows - I have a text file with an imagelist which contains the names of photos. The photos reside somewhere else on a hard drive.

How do I delete/move those photos which names are in imagelist? Is there any batch routine?

Comment: Start with the `for /f` command and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read file content line per line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231548/how-to-read-file-content-line-per-line)

Comment: Are all those files in the same directory? Do you have just the NAMES of the photos or the FILENAMES of the photo-files in your tet file?

Comment: @DlanodKcud Yes, all those files are in the same directory and the text file contains the filenames of those photo files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very simple sample should help you get going:

```
set filename=files.txt
set targetdir=bar
set sourcedir=foo

for /f %%i in (%filename%) do move "%sourcedir%\%%i" "%targetdir%"

pause
```

Note that there is absolutely no error handling. The pause at the end keeps the command window open so you can review the output

type for /? at the command prompt to get help for this command